# Context Menu - Menu Item Alignment Wpf

Tags: wpf

I have created a context menu and added menuitems to it like below,

```
<ContextMenu Width="150">
  <MenuItem Header="Refresh Data"/>
  <MenuItem Header="Show Prefilter"/>
  <MenuItem Header="Show Field List" Command="local:PivotGridCommands.ShowFieldList"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Here i have specified width too. The problem is if i mouse over on any of the menu item the item moves a step left ???

Why is it so ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely no WPF expert but I can reproduce your situation.

If I remove the Width specifier, the behavior is not seen. Something like this:

```
<ContextMenu>
```

I believe the situation arises based on the width you've specified for the contextmenu and the widths of the items you've put in the context menu.  If I insert shorter strings, the behavior doesn't occur.  Likewise, if I increase the specified Width to 200, I don't see the behavior with the given strings.